# Relationship doesn't updated in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When user update the property Curso (type Curso), this update does not work in Entity Framework. All data in object of type Turma are updated, but property Curso. Follow bellow my code:

This is the data received by PUT method in MVC controller:

```
{
    "Id":1,
    "DataVencimento":"2017-11-24T00:00:00",
    "Nome":".Net MVCss",
    "Turno":"Tarde",
    "Curso":
     {
        "Id":1,
         "Nome":"teste",
         "Duracao":2,
         "ValorAnuidade":5888.88,
         "QtdParcelas":2,
         "ValorParcela":22.22,
         "ValorMatricula":22.22,
         "Disciplinas":null,
         "CorpoDocente":null,
         "Documentos":null,
         "Turmas":null
     }
}
```

This is PUT method in MVC Controller:

```
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Update(TurmaDto dto)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    IKernel ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
    ninjectKernel.Bind<ITurmaBLO>().To<TurmaBLO>();
    ITurmaBLO blo = ninjectKernel.Get<ITurmaBLO>();

    Turma t = Mapper.Map<TurmaDto, Turma>(dto);

    if (!blo.Update(t))
    {
        response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Turma não encontrada.");
    }
    else
    {
        response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, t);
    }

    return response;
}
```

This is Class TurmaBLO:

```
public class TurmaBLO : GenericaBLO<Turma>, ITurmaBLO
{
    private IKernel ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
    private ITurmaDAO _dao;

    public TurmaBLO()
    {
        ninjectKernel.Bind<ITurmaDAO>().To<TurmaDAO>();
        _dao = ninjectKernel.Get<ITurmaDAO>();
    }

    public override bool Add(Turma e)
    {
        return _dao.Add(e);
    }

    public override bool Update(Turma e)
    {
        return _dao.Update(e);
    }

    public override List<Turma> GetAll()
    {
        return _dao.GetAll();
    }

    public override Turma Get(int id)
    {
        return _dao.Get(id);
    }
}
```

This is Class GenericaBLO:

```
public class GenericaBLO<T> : IGenericaBLO<T> where T : class
{

    public GenericaDAO<T> dao;

    public virtual bool Add(T e)
    {
        dao = new GenericaDAO<T>();
        return dao.Add(e);
    }

    public virtual bool Update(T e)
    {
        dao = new GenericaDAO<T>();
        return dao.Update(e);
    }

    public virtual bool Delete(T e)
    {
        dao = new GenericaDAO<T>();
        return dao.Delete(e);
    }

    public virtual List<T> GetAll()
    {
        dao = new GenericaDAO<T>();
        return dao.GetAll();
    }

    public virtual T Get(int id)
    {
        dao = new GenericaDAO<T>();
        return dao.Get(id);
    }

    public void ValidateForAdd()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ValidateForUpdate()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ValidateForDelete()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This is Class TurmaDAO:

```
internal class TurmaDAO : GenericaDAO<Turma>, ITurmaDAO
{
    public override bool Add(Turma e)
    {
        base.Context.Curso.Attach(e.Curso);
        return base.Add(e);
    }

    public override bool Update(Turma e)
    {
        base.Context.Curso.Attach(e.Curso);            
        return base.Update(e);
    }

    public override List<Turma> GetAll()
    {
        return base.Context.Turma.Include(c => c.Curso).Include(dt => dt.Descontos).ToList();
    }

    public override Turma Get(int id)
    {
        return base.Context.Turma.Include(c => c.Curso).Include(dt => dt.Descontos).SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
    }
}
```

This is Class GenericaDAO:

```
public class GenericaDAO<T> : IGenericaDAO<T> where T : class
{
    internal ApplicationDbContext Context  { get; set; }

    protected DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }

    public GenericaDAO()
    {
        Context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        DbSet = Context.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual bool Add(T e)
    {
        try
        {
            Context.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Added;
            Context.SaveChanges();
            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public virtual bool Update(T e)
    {
        try
        {
            Context.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Modified;
            Context.SaveChanges();
            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public virtual bool Delete(T e)
    {
        try
        {
            Context.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            Context.SaveChanges();
            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public virtual List<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet.ToList();
    }

    public virtual T Get(int id)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(id);
    }
}
```

This is Class TurmaDto:

```
public class TurmaDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataVencimento { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Turno { get; set; }
    public CursoDto Curso { get; set; }
}
```

This is Class Turma:

```
public class Turma
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataVencimento { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Turno { get; set; }
    public Curso Curso { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve], emphasis on **minimal**. You don't need 300 lines of code and two layers of abstraction to reproduce this.

Comment: You must double check that Curso EntityState is set to modified. This possibly is missing the relation type between Curso and Turma. Under the GenericaDAO<T> , the T is set to modified, what is T in Turma, the T as in Curso does not get entity state changed.

Comment: Why are you even hiding Entity Framework under two more layers of abstraction? What a huge waste of programming time. You are also leaving aside all of the `async` features of Entity Framework, making your entire code even much, much worse.

Comment: Madax, I've already set state of Curso as changed and did not work.

Comment: Ok CodeCaster. Sorry.

Comment: Camilo, I am beginner. This is my best at this moment. Do you have any tip for improve my code?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to call `Update` on the child entities, in your case `Curso`. So:

```
ITurmaBLO bloT = ninjectKernel.Get<ITurmaBLO>();
ICursoBLO blo = ninjectKernel.Get<ICursoBLO>();
Turma t = Mapper.Map<TurmaDto, Turma>(dto);

if(!(bloT.Update(t) && bloC.Update(t.Curso))){
      response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Turma não encontrada.");
}
```

If you need to only update the relation from `Turma` to `Curso` without changing the `Curso`, it's enough to set `Turma.CursoId` to the Id of the new `Curso`, assuming the relationship is mapped correctly in EF.

Comment: I need only update the property t.Curso. I do not need update properties of Course.